# Javascript on iPad: typewriting effect shuffles chars when idling the tab

Tags: javascript, ipad, settimeout

I made a little plugin that creates a typewriting effect:

```
$.fn.typewriter = function(options) {
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            text: "",
            animationDelay: 70,
            callback: null,
            callbackData: null
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

    $.each(settings.text.split(''), function (i, letter) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $this.text($this.text() + letter);

            if(i === settings.text.length - 1) {
                settings.callback(settings.callbackData);
            }

        }, settings.animationDelay * i);
    });
};
```

This works pretty nice, but on iPad, when the effect is in progress, I change the tab and come back later all the letters that are printed in this idle time are shuffled randomly. This does not happen on Desktop.

I guess this has something to do with the idling of the javascript execution when I am idling the tab. And it seems to be browser independent. So I'm guessing that the iPad somehow exeutes all the idled setTimeouts at the same time.? Is there some workaround to still get the letters in the correct order?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1wdkfjov/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to `setInterval` seems to fix the problem:

```
$.fn.typewriter = function(options) {
    var $this = this,
        defaults = {
            text: "",
            animationDelay: 70,
            callback: null,
            callbackData: null
        },
        settings = $.extend(defaults, options),
        timer;

    settings.text= settings.text.split('');
    timer= setInterval(function() {
      $this.append(settings.text[0]);
      settings.text.shift();
      if(!settings.text.length) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        if(settings.callback) {
          settings.callback(settings.callbackData);
        }
      }
    }, settings.animationDelay);
};
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8ufwfvm9/1/)